# React useRef return undefined error when trying to set the input property

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

I have used useRef hook from react

```
const myInput = useRef()
```

And pass it to material-ui OutlinedInput component

```
<OutlinedInput
  id="outlined-adornment-amount"                                      
  inputRef={myInput}
  type="file"                                            
  startAdornment={<InputAdornment position="start">
                   <FolderIcon fill="#333" />
                    </InputAdornment>}
                      labelWidth={60}
    />
```

when I try to set the input's property in within useEffect

```
  useEffect(() => {
        myInput.current.directory = true
    }, [])
```

I get

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'directory' of undefined

Comment: Yeah, this can happen because your useEffect came in before the component, you can try to add myInput?.current.directory = true or myInput && myInput.current.directory = true

Comment: Try this `if (myInput.current) { myInput.current.directory = true }`

Comment: @Fried noodles I'm getting error 'incorrect left-hand side in assignment expression'

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any problem with your code. I tested and everything works fine. Check out this:

https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-kare-u5rgm

Comment: The attribute isn't setting tho. It still behaves as a file selector than a folder selector. I have even tried myInput.current.setAttribute('webkitdirectory', ''); still not working

Comment: sandbox expired

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. In my project there were several MUI components and the input was on a modal. In my case what worked was to use a timeout. Not sure if it's the best solution, but it works:

```
  const myInputRef = useRef();
....
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      myInputRef.current.focus();
    }, 0);
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's because the input you used is not actually the input.
I think if you log your ref you would have 2 children.